# OCaml error type with Num

Tags: types, ocaml

I have got problem with type Num.num .
I need to use Num instead int, but program got error.
Please help me. Thanks.

```
#   open Num;;
#   let rec silnia n = 
#   if n < 2 
#   then 1
#   else n * silnia(n-1)
# 
#   let rec newton n k =
#   silnia n / (silnia k * silnia (n-k))
# 
#   let bell = [|1;1;2;5;15;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0|]
# 
#   let i = ref 2
#   let k = ref 0
#   let x = ref 0
#   let z = ref 0
#   let suma = ref 0
# 
#   let n = ref 5;;

val silnia : Num.num -> Num.num = <fun>
val newton : Num.num -> Num.num -> Num.num = <fun>
val bell : Num.num array = [|Num 1;Num 1;Num 0;Num 0;Num 0;Num 0;Num 0;Num 0;Num 0;Num 0;Num 0;Num 0;Num 0;Num 0;Num 0;Num 0;Num 0;Num 0;Num 0;Num 0;Num 0|]
val i : Num.num ref = {contents = Num 2}val k : Num.num ref = {contents = Num 0}
val x : Num.num ref = {contents = Num 0}
val z : Num.num ref = {contents = Num }
val suma : Num.num ref = {contents = Num 0}
val n : Num.num ref = {contents = Num 4}

# if !n != 0 || !n != 1 then
#   while !i <= !n do   
#      while !k <= (!i-1) do
#        x := newton (!i-1) !k;
#        suma := !suma + (!x * bell.(!k));
#        k := !k + 1 
#      done;
#     bell.(!k)<-(!suma);   
#     suma:=0;
#     i:= !i + 1;
#   done;;
File "", line 5, characters 29-31:
Error: This expression has type Num.num
     but an expression was expected of type int
```

I don't know how to fix it. Please correct it or give me some advice. Thanks.

Comment: "got an error" is not nearly specific enough

Comment: this is line 5: 
#        suma := !suma + (!x * bell.(!k));

File "", line 5, characters 29-31:
Error: This expression has type Num.num
     but an expression was expected of type int

Answer (score 1):

The * operator expects int operands. Need to use * from the `Num` module.

**Update**

I didn't notice that you're opening Num module--sorry. I personally wouldn't do that, as there are too many conflicts with pervasives.

I now suspect your problem is with the array index `bell.(!k)`. The index should be an int. You should be able to use `bell.(int_of_num !k)`.

Comment: How should this line look like?
# suma := !suma + (!x * bell.(!k));

Comment: I think I'm wrong--you are opening Num module. You still have the problem of mixing numeric types. E.g., array indices are int.